# How to get API data in multi picker React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

API response

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "postcode-0001",
            "text": "0200"
        },
        {
            "id": "postcode-00010",
            "text": "2607"
        },
]}
```

I am using this dependency: react-native-multiple-select

I want to add the API data to be included in the multi picker and this is my code

```
const [postcode, setPostcodes] = useState([]);

const responsepostal = await axios.post
            (`${urldemo}postal-codes`)
        setDataPostal(responsepostal.data.result)
```

This my return code for styling

Issue: the API postcode data in the multi-picker does not show. I don't want more than three postcode data in the multi-picker

```jsx
<MultiSelect
  style={GlobalSS.picker}
  selectedValue={postcode}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setPostcodes(itemValue)}
  // items={postcode}
  selectedItems={postcode}
  // onSelectedItemsChange={postcode}

  selectText="Select Postcode"
  searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Post Code"
  altFontFamily="ProximaNova-Light"
  tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
  tagBorderColor="#CCC"
  tagTextColor="#CCC"
  selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
  selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
  itemTextColor="#000"
  displayKey="name"
  searchInputStyle={{ color: "#CCC" }}
  submitButtonColor="#CCC"
  submitButtonText="Submit"
>
  {/* <Picker.Item color='grey'
        label=
        "Select Postcode"
        // {postcode} 
        value=
        ""
    // {postcode} 
    /> */}

  {datapostal.map((item) => (
    <Picker.Item label={item.text} value={item.id} />
  ))}
</MultiSelect>;
```

Answer (score 0):

use items props

```
<MultiSelect
  style={GlobalSS.picker}
  selectedValue={postcode}
  items={postcode}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setPostcodes(itemValue)}
  // items={postcode}
  selectedItems={postcode}
  // onSelectedItemsChange={postcode}

  selectText="Select Postcode"
  searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Post Code"
  altFontFamily="ProximaNova-Light"
  tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
  tagBorderColor="#CCC"
  tagTextColor="#CCC"
  selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
  selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
  itemTextColor="#000"
  displayKey="name"
  searchInputStyle={{ color: "#CCC" }}
  submitButtonColor="#CCC"
  submitButtonText="Submit"
/>
```

Comment: it didn't work for me. i get this error after i edit my code : Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `EditMyJobs

Comment: also i get this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'renderItems.length') when i used 
 items={postcode}   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setPostcodes(itemValue)} in multi picker

Comment: you should use your "responsepostal" function under useEffect it will resolve your issue.